# Find regex expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex expression to match strings with 4 repeating digits and optional hyphens in between, such as:

-3-3-3-3-
-1111-
2222-
0-0-00

Currently I have:

`\-?(\d(\-*))\1{3}\-?`

which matches the first two but not the last two. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^-?(\d)(?:-?\1){3}-?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AebXmw/1/). To find the pattern in a larger string, remove the `^` and `$` anchors:

```
-?(\d)(?:-?\1){3}-?
```

If the pattern is a part of a longer pattern, you might have to adjust the backreference number (if there are other capturing groups in the pattern).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `(\d)` - Group 1: any digit
- `(?:-?\1){3}` - three occurrences of an optional `-` and then the same value as captured in Group 1
- `-?` - an optional hyphen
- `$` -  end of the string.

Comment: Nice. I tried to upvote it immediately but it wouldn't allow. Thanks for the solution :)